# AIR HTMLLoader not showing PDF toolbar in Windows XP

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Hello My Flex AIR App HTMLLoder() showing PDF and its toolbar Nice in Mac but under Windows XP its showing PDF but not showing PDF toolbar how can i solve it? Any one have IDEA Please?

see this Mac screen:
http://beeitltd.com/dev/stackoverflow/Screen-shot1.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PDF toolbar used is based on the Adobe Acrobat Reader installed on the machine.

Here's a quote from their documentation:

> The Adobe Reader browser plug-in controls display of PDF files in an
>   AIR application, so modifications to the Reader toolbar interface
>   (such as those for position, anchoring, and visibility) persist in
>   subsequent viewing of PDF files in both AIR applications and the
>   browser.

The solution would be to install or update your Adobe Reader browser plug-in on your Windows machine.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb4.html